# Anchor Tag that targets content in the same page not working

Tags: html

I have a simple html question that I am struggling to solve. I would like to create an anchor that will direct the user to specific content within the same page. However, instead directing to the content, just refreshes the page.

The content below is what I did to jump to a point on the same page, so I did the following:

```
  <p><a href="#arcadia" name="arcadia">Arcadia</a></p>
```

and the content I want to jump to when it is clicked is the following:

```
<h4><b><img alt="" id="arcadia" name="arcadia" src="/Image/location-marker-blue.png" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; position: relative; left: -5px;" />Arcadia: Primary Care</b></h4>
```

However, as I mentioned, it just refreshes the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/03zr2kvd/

Comment: What browser are you using? I am in Chrome v64 and it works fine, but you should not have two elements with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the way you wrote it, although I wouldn't use the same `name` attribute value twice. You just need content that creates enough vertical distance both between anchor and link and below the anchor to see the effect:

```css
.x {
height: 800px;
background: #eee;
}
```

```html
  <p class="x"><a href="#arcadia">Arcadia</a></p>


<h4><b><img alt="" id="arcadia" name="arcadia" src="http://placehold.it/40x24/fa0" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; position: relative; left: -5px;" />Arcadia: Primary Care</b></h4>
  <p class="x">another high element</p>
```

Comment: @ Johannes: I tried that approach but it is not working. Is their a way to force it to go to that section?

Comment: There must be a different error in your code - this method definitely works